# In MVC3 how to get a list of models with Linq?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

In my database context class I have:

```
Imports System.Data.Entity
Public Class MusicStoreEntities
    Inherits DbContext
    Public Property Albums As DbSet(Of Album)
    Public Property Descriptions As DbSet(Of Description)
End Class
```

Then, I have those two models for Album and Description

```
Public Class Album
    Public Property AlbumId As Integer
End Class

Public Class Description
    Public Property DescriptionId As Integer
    Public Property AlbumId As Integer
End Class
```

From an Action of a Controller I can get a single Description for an Album using Linq as the following:

```
Dim album_description As Description = db.Descriptions.Single(Function(g) g.AlbumId = id)
```

However, how can I get a list of Descriptions for an Album?

```
Dim album_descriptions As List(Of Description) = db.Descriptions.**???**(Function(g) g.AlbumId = id)
```

Comment: So there's a 1-to-* relationship between `Album` and `Description`? You should probably add `Public Property Descriptions` to `Album` and let EF do it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `.Where()` method, documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338811.aspx).

```
db.Descriptions.Where(Function(g) g.AlbumId = id).ToList()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  Dim album_descriptions As List(Of Description) = db.Descriptions.Where(Function(g) g.AlbumId = id).ToList()
```

should do it